# What about the rank of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

**Problem:** Suppose $0<r<n$. Suppose $A:\mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$. Suppose that he rank of $A(t)$ il less or equal $r$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. What be said about the rank of $A'(0)$?

**Attempt:** I tried using the fact that $rank(A)=k$ if and only $k$ is the maximum size of an invertible minor $B$. I would like to say that $rank(A'(0)) \leq r$ but I am not sure if it is true. Of course $rank(A'(0))$ could be $r$ because we can define $A(t)$ as the diagonal matrix with the first $r$ elements equal to $t$ and anywhere else equal to $0$.

Comment: Consider a matrix with the first $r-1$ diagonal positions containing a $1$ and the $r$-th being $t$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField My claim is that $rank(A'(0)) \leq r$.

Comment: And as you noted it can be $r$ so all that's left is to verify it can be less than $r$. Note that differentiation is a linear transformation so the rank cannot increase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{rank}(A(t))\le r$ for every $t$, the rank of the differential quotient $\frac{A(t)-A(0)}{t}$ is at most $2r$. It follows that the rank of $A'(0)$ is also $\le2r$. The example in the other answer has already illustrated the case where $\operatorname{rank}(A'(0))=2r$.

Answer (score 5):

In general, the rank of $A'(0)$ can be larger than $r$. Consider for example $A(t) \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{R})$ given by
$$ A(t) = \begin{bmatrix} t & t^2 \\ 1 & t \end{bmatrix}. $$
Then $A(t)$ has rank one for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ but
$$ A'(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
has rank two.

---

In general, you can obtain an explicit relation between $A'(0)$ and $A(0)$. A matrix $A$ has rank $\leq r$ iff $\Lambda^{r+1}(A) = 0$. This is a fancy but useful way of saying that all the $(r + 1) \times (r+1)$ minors of $A$ vanish. In your case, you have $\Lambda^{r+1}(A(t)) \equiv 0$. Differentiating this condition and plugging $t = 0$ you get that we must have
$$ A'(0)v_1 \wedge A(0)v_2 \wedge \dots \wedge A(0)v_{k+1} + A(0)v_1 \wedge A'(0)v_2 \wedge \dots \wedge A(0)v_{k+1} + \\
\dots + A(0)v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge A(0)v_k \wedge A'(0) v_{k+1} = 0 $$
for all $v_1,\dots,v_{k+1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

This is a system of linear equations on $A'(0)$ (where we assume $A(0)$ is fixed). Depending on what your initial matrix $A(0)$ is, the system might or might not put a restriction on $A'(0)$ but not necessarily a restriction on the rank of $A'(0)$.

Comment: What do you mean with $\Lambda^{r+1}(A)$?

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini: The exterior power of $A$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra).

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately I have not studied wedge product yet.

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini: No problem. Basically you have a vector-valued smooth function $F(A)$ which outputs the determinants of all possible $(r+1) \times (r+1)$ minors of $A$. The fact that $A$ has rank $\leq r$ is equivalent to $F(A)=0$. Then you have $F(A(t)) \equiv 0$ so by differentiating it, you get a condition on $A'(0)$. Namely, $dF|_{A(0)}(A'(0)) = 0$. Writing $F$ as an exterior power allows you to easily calculate the differential and that's the only use of the exterior power in my answer.